# How can I build an Eigen::Map to a matlab::data::Array object that I intend to populate with data

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, mex

This question is a follow up to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353633/efficient-method-to-pass-large-arrays-from-matlab-to-c-eigen-using-map-class/76353749#76353749) about building an Eigen::Map to an input matlab::data::Array object in the Matlab Data API for C++. Now I want to know how I can implement something similar but to an output array which I will populate with data as I loop through it.

In the previous question, I implemented the linked solution from [Matlab's forums](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1573713-c-mex-data-api-how-can-i-get-the-raw-pointer-of-an-array-input-without-copying-it). Here, I tried using the following to get a non-const pointer:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T* getOutDataPtr(matlab::data::Array arr) {
  matlab::data::TypedArray<T> arr_t = arr;
  matlab::data::TypedIterator<T> it(arr_t.begin());
  return it.operator->();
}
```

Which is used like so:

```cpp
// Initialize input parameters
long int numEl = inputs[0][0];
long int na = inputs[0][1];
long int nPoints = inputs[0][2];
        
// Preallocate output and define map to output array
outputs[0] = factory.createArray<double>
  ({static_cast<size_t>(nPoints),static_cast<size_t>(numEl*na)});
        
auto ptrRecon = getOutDataPtr<double>(outputs[0]);
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> Recon(ptrRecon,nPoints,numEl*na);

for(int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {
 for(int n = 0; n < na; n++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < numEl; j++) {
   Recon(i,n*numEl + j) = 5.0;
  }
 }    
}
```

Even with a simple assignment like that however, I encounter runtime errors after compiling and Matlab crashes. What exactly is going wrong?

**Additional Trials**
I also tried the following for the inner loop which does seem to work:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {
    for(int n = 0; n < na; n++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numEl; j++) {
            outputs[0][i][n*numEl + j] = 5.0;

        }
    }    
}
```

I suspect this means there's some issue with the way I am getting the pointer to the output matlab data array?

Comment: The Eigen side of things looks fine (except that you should put the outermost loop innermost for better locality of data, column-major format and all that; but that doesn't affect correctness). How large are the dimensions? `long int` on Windows is the same size as `int`, both smaller than `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t`, a.k.a. `Eigen::Index`. So I wonder if you ran into integer overflows

Comment: `nPoints` is ~100,000. `na` and `numEl` are 75 and 192 respectively. I added a line to print nPoints to the matlab console just to be sure there are no shenanigans going on and it printed out the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess because I'm going off the rather mediocre Matlab API documentation and don't have a Matlab license to test it with. So please take this with a grain of salt.

One difference that I see is that you create a mutable iterator `TypedIterator<T>` instead of the `TypedIterator<const T>` used in the Matlab forum. And you do this in a function that takes `matlab::data::Array` by value. This creates a [shared data copy](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.data.array.html#bvjdkkf-5). As I understand it, these are copy-on-write.

My hypothesis is that either constructing that iterator or using it in a manner that could modify that shared array "un-shares" it, effectively creating a copy. However, that copy would be limited to the life-time of the argument, meaning the function. After the function returns, that becomes a dangling pointer.

Try changing the function signature to `T* getOutDataPtr(matlab::data::Array& arr)`. Or inline the code into your main function.

### Edit

Actually, that change wouldn't be sufficient because you construct a `TypedArray<T>` from the `Array`. That also counts as a shared copy. Try this instead using [`getWritableElements`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.data.array.html#d124e7695):

```cpp
template <typename T>
T* getOutDataPtr(matlab::data::Array& arr) {
  auto range = matlab::data::getWritableElements<T>(arr);
  return range.begin().operator->();
}
```